# jGRASP (Java) entering a formula in java

Tags: java

I input this into java and these errors come out.  error ")" expected,  error not a statement , and error ";" expected. but i do not understand why?

```
  pent = n(3n-1)/2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java this would be

```
double pent = n * (3.0 * n - 1.0) / 2.0;
```